# How do I make a 16 bit integer into a 9 bit 2C number in C?

Tags: c

```
    var.immediate = (short)((16bit)&0x1FF);
```

I have this 16 bit unsigned value and I want to extract the first 9 bits of the instruction, as a signed 2C bit value. Currently its returning the signed 16 bit value and im unsure how to get the 9 bit signed value? any suggestions?

Comment: 16bit is not a valid variable. Can you post a [mcve] with what you're expecting and what you're getting ?

Comment: Old IBM machines had 9 bit bytes. But not sure what you intend to do with the parity bit.

Comment: If the platform, you are compiling your code for, supports 9 bit words, your compiler should provide you with 9 bit data types, so you should be able to jut cast the value into that `var.immediate =  (int9_t)(value)` alternatively, you can make `var.immediate` a 9bit bit field, if that's structure written by you... `value & 0x1FF` just masks the value, so you get 16 bits but the last 7 bits will be zero (like `0000000XXXXXXXXX`)

Answer (score 2):

Given an unsigned 16-bit `x`, the value of its high nine bits interpreted as two’s complement is `((int) (x>>7) ^ 1<<8) - (1<<8)`.

`(int) (x>>7)` gets the high nine bits of the 16 and converts to a signed type so we can work with negative values.

`^ 1<<8` flips the high bit of the nine. If it was 0, designating a nonnegative number in two’s complement, this makes it 1, designating 256 in the unsigned format. If it was 1, designating a negative number, this makes it 0.

Then `- (1<<8)` subtracts 256. If the sign bit were 0, this negates the 256 we added by the XOR above. If the sign bit were 1, this applies the two’s complement effect for a negation.

(If “first 9 bits” in the question means the low bits rather than the high bits, change `(int) (x>>7)` to `(int) (x & 0x1ff)`.)